# Existence of dense velocity curve on connected manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, vector-fields, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ be a non-empty, connected manifold. Show that there exists a differentiable curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to M $ , so that the image of the velocity curve $\dot{\gamma} :\mathbb{R} \to TM$ is dense on $TM$.

This is a problem on chapter 11 "Second order differential equations and spays" of Bröcker's book.

I have no clue on how to solve this, so any hint will be very appreciated.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I haven't thought about it much other than to ask this: Have you tried to solve the problem when $M=S^1$?

Comment: For any point $p$, one can always make a curve in $B_{R^{-1}}(p)$ so that its tangent vectors is $R^{-1}$ dense in $B_R(0)$ (I mean a set in $TB_R(p)$, say with some trivialization); if you like, call this a "$R$-dance". It is not hard to make a plan so that your curve comes back to any fixed region again and again, and do $R$-dance with bigger and bigger $R$...